# Android: Can you edit a view created in xml, in code?

Tags: android

Ok I have my main.xml defined like:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText android:text="EditText" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="175px"></EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="100px">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/btnPrint"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/btnCancel"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to be able to update the EditText's cursor position from code before the call to `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, is this possible?  If not, what is the xml attribute for setting the cursor position of an EditText View?

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to manipulate your view from the java side before your setContentView() call, because findViewById(R.id.yourView) will return null unless the view in question is actually on the screen. Is there a reason you don't want to do it like this?

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
et.setSelection(position);
```

Although the cursor will technically move after its visible, it is going to be so fast that users are unlikely to notice.

Comment: I want to do it which ever way I am supposed to lol.  I'm just new to this android programming thing.  Not used to the whole xml UI programming stuff.

Comment: I have another question, might as well ask it here.  I'm debugging my program through my phone.  Now, I've changed the main.xml but when the program loads on my phone it is still showing the layout that was originally in the helloworld example.

Comment: Did you install the new version on your phone? and did you just edit the main.xml file? or did you make a new xml file, if you made a new one you'll have to call setContentView() on that file instead of main. Also do you have multiple layout folders? like layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi etc? if so you'll have to change main.xml in which ever category your device falls under for it to reflect the changes on your device.

Comment: I deleted the one that was installed, and clicked the run button in the eclipse IDE again, but it seems like it installed the old one : (.  Yes, all I edited was the main.xml, there are no other xml files in res/layout.  No only one layout folder called 'layout'.  Thanks again,  Justin

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  I went out to the actual directory and looked at the xml file, all it contained was the <?xml version="1.0"...?>.  So I deleted it and then made a change to the main.xml in eclipse then saved it and the changes took on the device : ).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah ok, finally got to get it to run and got some button events going.  The setSelection move the cursor on the same line.  By default the first line is in the middle of the EditText.  How can I make the text start at the first line of the EditText box?  Thanks,  Justin

Answer (score 2):

You can not do any modifications to the views, which are not yet inflated. So, the first answer is **No**.

As for the second try this tag `<requestFocus />` within your edit text:

```
<EditText ...>
  <requestFocus />
<EditText/>
```

Comment: I'm guessing 'inflated' means created and visible on the screen (in the layout).  I'll try that requestFocus tag and see what happens, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inflate the view, then set the cursor position or make any changes that you want, then set pass this view to setContentView() method.